# Unable to debug in WebStorm "bad option: --expose_debug_as=v8debug"

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm

I am trying to debug my NodeJS code using WebStorm 2016.3 and NodeV8 and I am unable to debug it with this error

```
"bad option: - expose_debug_as=v8debug"
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this fixed by [updating](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download) my Webstorm to Webstorm 2017.x This will debug with Node 8.

Comment: *"to Webstorm 2017.2"* Latest version is 2017. **3** actually.

Comment: @LazyOne I have updated my answer - you can use Webstorm 2017.2 and above.

Comment: My point was: if you are telling to install newer version from a website then it should be the latest one (2017.3) and not previous (2017.2) -- nothing more than that.

Comment: It's simple, to-the-point solutions like this why I love Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Just add as Node parameter in Edit Configurations -> Node parameters : '**--inspect**'. Tested in Webstorm 2016.3 (Linux edition)